# jquery slider going back to the 1st li item issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

As i exploring around the internet, i found this simple jquery slider.

http://codepen.io/fixcl/pen/KwpKvb

here is html source

```
<div class="slider--teams">
<div class="slider--teams__team">
<ul id="list" class="cf">

  <li>
    <figure class="active">
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <figcaption>
        <h2>Billie</h2>
        <p>Head of Team</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>

  <li>
    <figure>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <figcaption>
        <h2>Roger</h2>
        <p>Art Director</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>

  <li>
    <figure>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <figcaption>
        <h2>Wendy</h2>
        <p>Designer</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>

  <li>
    <figure>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <figcaption>
        <h2>Bill</h2>
        <p>Development</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>

  <li>
    <figure>
      <div>
        <div></div> 
      </div>
      <figcaption>
        <h2>Lorraine</h2>
        <p>Front-End Development</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>

  <li>
    <figure>
      <div>
        <div></div> 
      </div>
      <figcaption>
        <h2>Wesley</h2>
        <p>Marketing Lead</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>

</ul>
```

and js source

```
    var sliderTeam = (function(document, $) {

      'use strict';

  var $sliderTeams = $('.slider--teams'),
  $list = $('#list'),
  $listItems = $('#list li'),
  $nItems = $listItems.length,
  $nView = 3,
  autoSlider,
  $current = 0,
  $isAuto = true,
  $acAuto = 2500,

      _init = function() {
    _initWidth();
    _eventInit();
  },

      _initWidth = function() {
    $list.css({
      'margin-left': Math.floor(100 / $nView) + '%',
      'width': Math.floor(100 * ($nItems / $nView)) + '%'
    });
    $listItems.css('width', 100 / $nItems + '%');
    $sliderTeams.velocity({ opacity: 1 }, { display: "block" }, { delay:1000 });
  },

     _eventInit = function() {

        window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function(callback, element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
    })();

    window.requestInterval = function(fn, delay) {
        if( !window.requestAnimationFrame       && 
            !window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame && 
            !window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    && 
            !window.oRequestAnimationFrame      && 
            !window.msRequestAnimationFrame)
                return window.setInterval(fn, delay);
        var start = new Date().getTime(),
        handle = new Object();

        function loop() {
            var current = new Date().getTime(),
            delta = current - start;
            if(delta >= delay) {
                fn.call();
                start = new Date().getTime();
            }
            handle.value = requestAnimFrame(loop);
        };
        handle.value = requestAnimFrame(loop);
        return handle;
    }

    window.clearRequestInterval = function(handle) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame ? window.cancelAnimationFrame(handle.value) :
        window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame ? window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame(handle.value)   :
        window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame ? window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame(handle.value) :
        window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame ? window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame(handle.value) :
        window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame ? msCancelRequestAnimationFrame(handle.value) :
        clearInterval(handle);
    };

    $.each($listItems, function(i) {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.on('touchstart click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        _stopMove(i);
        _moveIt($this, i);
      });
    });

    autoSlider = requestInterval(_autoMove, $acAuto);
  },

  _moveIt = function(obj, x) {

    var n = x;

    obj.find('figure').addClass('active');        
    $listItems.not(obj).find('figure').removeClass('active');

    $list.velocity({
      translateX: Math.floor((-(100 / $nItems)) * n) + '%',
      translateZ: 0
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: [400, 26],
      queue: false
    });

  },

  _autoMove = function(currentSlide) {
    if ($isAuto) { 
      $current = ~~(($current + 1) % $nItems);
    } else {
      $current = currentSlide;
    }
    console.log($current);
    _moveIt($listItems.eq($current), $current);
  },

  _stopMove = function(x) {
    clearRequestInterval(autoSlider);
    $isAuto = false;
    _autoMove(x);
  };

  return {
   init: _init
  };

})(document, jQuery);

$(window).load(function(){
  'use strict';
  sliderTeam.init();
});
```

it works perfectly fine, except that using it on my website has slightest problem.

it goes back automatically to the 1st li, without me doing anything.

it often goes back to the 1st li when i click furiously on the next li and it does that without me being able to see the very last li item.

im guessing something has collided in the js or the css.

can anyone help me out?

and here is my website that has problem. 
sorry, i couldn't generate the same problem using jsfiddle.
http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/today#

Comment: try changing `queue: true` in velocity

Comment: um. it seems to only accelerate the problem. now it doesn't even move when i click on the next item.

Comment: as i can see, in the `ul` a class in always getting updated.